# How to add major and minor grid lines using pcolor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

My goal is to add a thick set of grid marks over the existing ones I have created using pcolor (see code below). There would be one thick grid line for every N (5 for instance) thinner grid lines. The grid lines I want to add could be analogous to major tick marks while the existing grid lines could be analogous to minor tick marks.

My code:

```
Z = np.random.rand(25, 25)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[1,1,0.1])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
plt1 = ax1.pcolor(Z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, edgecolors='k', linewidths=1)

cbax = plt.subplot(gs[0,2])
cb = Colorbar(ax=cbax, mappable = plt1)
```

Output image:
[random data with grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um6IS.png)

Doctored image with red lines showing major grid I want: [same data with doctored red grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaror.png)

Does anyone have a good solution or work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by digging around in the [matplotlib.pyplot.grid documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html).

Here is my updated code:

```
Z = np.random.rand(25, 25)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[1,1,0.1])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
plt1 = ax1.pcolor(Z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, edgecolors='k', linewidths=1)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
ax1.grid(b=True, which='major', color='r', linestyle='-')

cbax = plt.subplot(gs[0,2])
cb = Colorbar(ax=cbax, mappable = plt1)
```

Output figure:
[random data with major and minor grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8snK.png)